# Numbers in descending order in Java using if/else only

Tags: java

How can I create a java program using only if / else to order 3 numbers in descending order. I can not use for processes or array. Numbers are entered by the user.
Here's what i have so far. What should i do, is the user enters two integers that are the same? The code can only display one output.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
public class DescendingOrder
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      //variable dec.
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

      //user prompt
      System.out.println("Please enter three integers");
      a=kbd.nextInt();
      b=kbd.nextInt();
      c=kbd.nextInt();

      //program output
      if (a>=b && b>=c && a>=c)
      {
         System.out.println("a b c");
      }

      if (a>=c && c>=b && a>=b )
      {   
         System.out.println("a c b");
      }   

      if (b>=a && a>=c && b>=c)
      {
         System.out.println("b a c");
      }

      if (b>=c && c>=a && b>=c)
      {      
          System.out.println("b c a");
      }

      if(c>=a && a>=b && c>=b)
      {
          System.out.println("c a b");
      }

      if (c>= b && b>=a && c>=a)
      {
         System.out.println("c b a"); 
      }   


   }
}
```

Comment: Which is it, 5 or 3? Your text says one thing, your code says another.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to output the numbers in descending order, the above code is not going to work. What you are printing is the sum of all three integers which no matter what will be the same (the order of the addition does not affect the output)

Comment: @Gacci how do i get the system out print line to display the numbers in descending order. and its 3 numbers sorry about that

Comment: This way you will print sum of these numbers, no matters in which order they are. Better to separate each of them by comma or quotes

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way you can do it is

```
if (a < b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

if (b < c)
{
    int temp = b;
    b = c;
    c = temp;
}


if (a < b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

If two numbers are the same it doesn't really matter, as 90 45 45 is the same as 90 45 45. (In the case of your code as written, however, you are correct in noticing that it does matter. You could fix this by changing all your if statements except the first one into else-if)

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a thought exercise so consider this answer an alternative to the other correct answers for your consideration. Here my enterprise-y solution.

Step 0, refactor your code to make it testable and stub out the method that will do the actual work:

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DescendingOrder {

    public static final void main(final String... args) { // unavoidable use of an array, please don't dock points
        try (final Scanner kbd = new Scanner(in)) { // always close your Closeables
            final int a = kbd.nextInt();
            final int b = kbd.nextInt();
            final int c = kbd.nextInt();
            final DescendingOrder calculator = new DescendingOrder();
            out.println(calculator.order(a, b, c));
        }
    }

    public String order(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Step 1, write a unit test:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE;
import static java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DescendingOrderTest {

    private DescendingOrder orderer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        orderer = new DescendingOrder();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testOrderABC() {
        final String result = orderer.order(MAX_VALUE, 0, MIN_VALUE); // don't forget the edge cases
        assertEquals(MAX_VALUE + " " + 0 + " " + MIN_VALUE, result);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testOrderACB() {
        final String result = orderer.order(13, 5, 8);
        assertEquals("13 8 5", result);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testOrderBAC() {
        final String result = orderer.order(4, 8, 2);
        assertEquals("8 4 2", result);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testOrderBCA() {
        final String result = orderer.order(-8, -2, -4); // don't forget negative numbers
        assertEquals("-2 -4 -8", result);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testOrderCAB() {
        final String result = orderer.order(1, -5, 5);
        assertEquals("5 1 -5", result);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testOrderCBA() {
        final String result = orderer.order(MAX_VALUE, 0, MIN_VALUE);
        assertEquals(MAX_VALUE + " " + 0 + " " + MIN_VALUE, result);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testAllSame() {
        final String result = orderer.order(53, 53, 53);
        assertEquals("53 53 53", result);
    }
}
```

Step 2, iteratively implement order until your tests pass:

```
    public String order(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
        if (a > b && a > c) {
            return a + " " + order(b, c);
        } else if (b > a && b > c) {
            return b + " " + order(a, c);
        }
        return c + " " + order(a, b);
    }

    protected String order(final int x, final int y) {
        if (x > y) {
            return x + " " + y;
        }
        return y + " " + x;
    }
```

It might not be the most computationally efficient, but I kept the method sizes small so it is clear what the code is meant to accomplish. I also do not need to scan through six scenarios to see that it is correct. If I assume that `order( int, int )` is correct, then I only need to work through three scenarios to see that `order( int, int, int )` is correct.

Obviously, this is overkill. But those constraints would never really exist.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code was fine you were just printing wrong. You have to understand that a,b,c are variable of type int. when you use the + operator with two ints it performs an addition. If you use the + operator with an int and with a string it produces a concatenation. The int 'calls' to string turning the int into a string which produces String + String = concatenation. 
Anyways, I think this is what you wanted. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Stackoverflow
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      //variable dec.
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

      //user prompt
      System.out.println("Please enter three integers");
      a=kbd.nextInt();
      b=kbd.nextInt();
      c=kbd.nextInt();

      //program output
      if (a>=b && b>=c && a>=c)
      {
         System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+c);
      }

      if (a>=c && c>=b && a>=b )
      {   
         System.out.println(a+" "+c+" "+b);
      }   

      if (b>=a && a>=c && b>=c)
      {
         System.out.println(b+" "+a+" "+c);
      }

      if (b>=c && c>=a && b>=c)
      {      
          System.out.println(b+" "+c+" "+a);
      }

      if(c>=a && a>=b && c>=b)
      {
          System.out.println(c+" "+a+" "+b);
      }

      if (c>= b && b>=a && c>=a)
      {
         System.out.println(c+" "+b+" "+a); 
      }   


   }
}
```

Comment: thank you! What should i do, is the user enters two integers that are the same? The code can only display one output. For example is the first two integers entered are both 5, and the third 4. The out has to result in 5, 5, 4

Comment: Please delete your down vote and future reference don't just down vote and run!

Comment: @Gacci Thanks! Sorry people are downvoting you, I understood your first answer. In your defense you were answering my question.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I just hate the egos in this website. People don't understand that we are all here to learn. At some point we all have posted a question. And that cliché that an answer has to be x-or-y long is outdated (like high school 3 paragraphs for and essay). Anyways, I am glad I was helpful.

Comment: One of the official ways of learning here is through downvoting and commenting. Your answer is much better now and this is what keeps the quality of this website. The first downvoter did a bad job not commenting, though.

Comment: @AndréNeves Sorry, it was not intended for you. You commented and removed your down vote!

Comment: I would have said something earlier (didn't downvote, btw), but didn't have enough reputation to comment at the time. Look at what happens with the code you provided when a = b = c. You need to include `else` so it doesn't go through the entire chain.